# Convert Word doc to ASPX?

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, document-conversion, format-conversion

Is there a simple way to do this that preserves formatting?

Answer (score 6):

Save it as HTML ?

Comment: http://www.textism.com/wordcleaner/ or http://www.algotech.dk/word-html-cleaner-input.htm ?